# How to access iOS evironment variables or runtime arguments with react-native?

Tags: react-native

I want to load a different configuration depending on the evironent (dev, qa, prod). Before react-native I used NODE_ENV and enfivy. But in react-native there of isn't a global process variable. How do I access iOS evironment variables or runtime arguments with react-native?

Thanks,
Georg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should write a [native module](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/nativemodulesios.html#content) which can get the environment variables and export them to the JS.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Yinfeng. For my project I write a native module to expose the configuration parameters to react native. So that I don't have to maintain 2 set of application parameters in React-Native and Swift code.